# How to expand manual folds

Tags: vim

Let's say I fold the following text:

```
45 def hello():
46    print ('hello')
```

And I fold those two lines of code, so I now have:

```
45 +--  2 lines: def hello():---
```

Then let's say I need to follow our coding standard which requires two blank lines after every function, so now the function is:

```
45 def hello():
46    print ('hello')
47
48
```

Is there a way to expand that fold two coder those additional lines? Or is the way to do this that I need to do `zd`...`zf` again?

Comment: Just for clarity, when you say "expand the fold" you mean *extend* the fold to include additional lines, not *open* the fold, correct?

Comment: @hobbs -- yes exactly, to change the fold from lines 45-46 to 45-48